# Vertical alignment on text and fontawesome icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I want to create a custom alert box with bootstrap.
But the vertical aligment of the text and the icon, does not work. So here`s the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="alert-box alert-box-info text-center clearfix" style="display: inline-block;">
     <i class="fa fa-info text-info pull-left"></i>
     <div class="text text-info"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.alert-box
{
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
}
.alert-box .fa {
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.alert-box .text {
    margin: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.alert-box-info
{
    background: #f4f8fa;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #5bc0de;
}
.alert-box-info h4
{
    color: #5bc0de;
}
```

The [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zoker/qnj3ohqh/)

Can somebody tell me, why the vertical alignment does not work and how I can fix that?

Comment: vertical alignment affects included objects only and doesn't object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer was completely updated as a result of [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435892/flex-box-text-items-overflow).**

---

Your layout should be achievable with flex-box. Just add on the container:

```
display: flex;
align-items:center;
```

Anything `table` related of `vertical align` related should be removed from all places. You can create your desired layout by forcing table layout on some elements, but that is not the way to go here since you don't have a real table and tabular data.

*Note: We need to explicitly add `flex-shrink: 0` on the small columns on the edges because of a Chrome bug (just fixed for FF 34) that causes incorrect shrinking. According to the specs, there should not happen any shrinking by default.*

### Demo:

```css
.alert-box
{
    margin: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
 display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    height: 100px
}
.alert-box .fa {
 font-size: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.alert-box .text {
 margin: 0px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.alert-box-info
{
    background: #f4f8fa;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #5bc0de;
}
.alert-box-info h4
{
    color: #5bc0de;
}
.alert-btn {
 flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="alert-box alert-box-info text-center clearfix">
 <i class="fa fa-info text-info"></i>
 <div class="text text-info"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p></div>
    <div class="alert-btn"><a href="google.com" class="btn btn-lg btn-info">Test</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Made some updates to have it working also with small content.

Comment: And what, when I add a button which is another table-cell: http://jsfiddle.net/Zoker/qnj3ohqh/13/ The button just overflows the box

Comment: I've reduced your problem to this: http://jsfiddle.net/qnj3ohqh/16/ , but now I will go to sleep. I'll post updates tomorrow if I can figure out why it overflows. Also please remove everything in your code related to table or vertical align as it's useless.

Comment: So far this looks like a browser rendering bug. The only one that does the computations correctly, surprisingly, is IE. An even more basic example: http://jsfiddle.net/qnj3ohqh/19/

Comment: Just tell me, when you have found the issue :)

Comment: @Zoker It looks like this is a browser bug. It doesn't happen in IE11 and FF34 as far as I could find out. One solution would be to set explicit width for the left and right columns. Also other CSS alternatives and workarounds exist. Just not the ones with vertical align.

Comment: @Zoker So... I don't want to invest any more time into this. I spent too much already. Until the Flex-box is fixed in Webkit you may use the table alternative I added to the answer.

Comment: @Zoker Good news! It seems there was an easy solution for this to make the flexbox work as intended. Check the updated answer and demo.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to change style of div:

```
<div class="alert-box alert-box-info text-center clearfix" style="display: table-cell;  vertical-align: middle;">
```

Comment: That's a hack... don't use display table cell outside of tables.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is the best option here. I've added `transition` for `line-height` for smooth alignment.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/qnj3ohqh/12/)

```js
function doMath() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('fa-info')[0].style.lineHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('text')[0].clientHeight + 'px';
}
doMath();
window.onresize = doMath;
```

```css
.alert-box {
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  display: table;
}
.alert-box .fa {
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  transition: line-height 0.1s;
}
.alert-box .text {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.alert-box-info {
  background: #f4f8fa;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #5bc0de;
}
.alert-box-info h4 {
  color: #5bc0de;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="alert-box alert-box-info text-center clearfix" style="display: inline-block;"> <i class="fa fa-info text-info pull-left"></i>

  <div class="text text-info">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no need for JS.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to vertical align a text if it has only 1 row is the line-height properties:

```
.alert-box .fa {
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    line-height: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Clear/qnj3ohqh/15/

Comment: If you want a "clear" solution, don't put a fixed height in px! Don't specific an height and put a padding to top and bottom!