# Flex-box text items overflow

Tags: css, flexbox

Could anyone please explain why the width of the columns containing text is not computed correctly to fully contain the text in each of the columns?
On Firefox and Chrome, the text in the first and third column will not fit the boxes, but surprisingly the boxes are sized correctly in IE 11?

Is this a browser bug?

```css
.box {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    height: 100px;
}
.box > div {
    border: 1px solid Pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div>Firstitem</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</div>
    <div>Lastitem</div>
</div>
```

I'm not interested in alternatives. I want to know the reason why this happens. (That is why I reduced this situation to something very basic.)

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I guess it is a bug - I originally read the spec the wrong way around. "By default, flex items *won’t* shrink below their minimum content size (the length of the longest word or fixed-size element)" - ([link](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-common)). It's worth noting that your example has no overflow problem in the latest Firefox stable 34.0.5. This may now be restricted to webkit based browsers (including the Chrome fork) as this behaviour *is* present in Safari

Comment: @misterManSam Thanks for the docs link and the FF info!

Comment: @misterManSam Thanks for the workaround, but I don't really need it. I don't need this particular layout for anything. I just ran into it while answering some other question on SO and wanted to find out what's wrong.

Comment: Fair enough, I would guess that the bug is something to do with the [initial `min-width` auto value](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#min-size-auto) being incorrectly calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happens here in Chrome & Firefox 33:

1. Each flex item establishes a `flex base size`, which in this case is their `max-content width` (the width if all the text is laid out on a single line, basically). Note that this is *HUGE* in the case of the middle flex item.
2. The flex container tries to give each flex item their requested `flex base size`, but there's not enough space to go around (because the second one is greedy). So, we go into "shrink" mode.
3. Each flex item has, by default, `flex-shrink:1` -- so each flex item receives a portion of the negative free-space, to make them sum to the correct final size. (The amount each item receives is proportional to their `flex-shrink` and also proportional to their `flex base size`, so that bigger things shrink more than small things.)

So, each flex item ends up shrinking to be a bit smaller than its requested `flex base size`, which means the first & last items have a bit of overflow, and the middle item has to wrap its lines (poor thing).

As indicated in the comments, the spec *also* (relatively recently) added a default `min-width` for flex items, which generally ends up being their `min-content width` (their width if all optional linebreaks are taken) -- and it prevents flex items from being shrunk below that minimum size. I [added support for this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984711) in Firefox 34, and I believe IE supports this in their current "tech preview" as well. I'm not sure when WebKit/Blink will add support -- I [filed a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426898) a few months ago to be sure it's on the Chrome team's radar, at least.

Anyway -- if you want to work around this in browsers that don't yet support `min-width:auto`, just set `flex:none` on the flex items that you don't want to shrink -- the first and last items, in your snippet.  That zeroes out their `flex-shrink` value, which means in step 3 above, the middle flex item will get all of the negative space.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Any reason why I shouldn't just use `flex-shrink: 0` only?

Comment: That works too. "flex: none" is equivalent to "flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 0; flex-basis: auto".  And flex-shrink is the only non-default thing there, so you could just set that.

Comment: ("flex:none" may be slightly better because: (1) it's a bit more human-readable about your intent, and (2) it won't break if you happen to accidentally set "flex-grow" or "flex-basis" via another style rule.  I believe the CSS working group generally recommends using shorthands instead of longhand properties where possible (e.g. 'background'), because usually when you want to set one piece of a shorthand, you really want all of its sub-properties to behave like you expect (rather than getting set by some other style rule and getting a mish-mash).